# Поиск значения второй производной функции в точке(Интерполирование куб.сплайнами)

Tags: c++, математика

Моя задача - найти значение второй производной функции в заданной точке. На вход я имею количество точек,точку в которой ищется производная,граничные условия,аргументы и значения функции в точках. Не могли бы вы подсказать, где я допустил ошибку в коде,ведь для функции-константы программы выдаёт неверный результат.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
 
using namespace std;
 
struct dot {
    double x, y;
};
 
//проверка упорядоченности агрументов функции
bool check_order(dot* X, int N) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N - 1; i++)
        if (X[i].x > X[i + 1].x)
            return false;
    return true;
}
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    ifstream input("input.txt");
    ofstream output("output.txt");
    if (input && output) {
        int N,IER = 0;   //N - количество точек
        double XX;       //ХХ - точка в которой мы ищем значение второй производной 
        double A, B;     //Граничные условия
        double YY;       //значение второй производной функции в т. ХХ
        try {
 
            //
            // Ввод информации 
            //
 
            input >> N >> XX;
            input >> A >> B;
            if (N < 3) throw - 1;
            dot* X = new dot[N];
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)       //аргументы функции
                input >> X[i].x;
            if (!check_order(X, N)) throw true;
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)         //значение функции в заданных точках
                input >> X[i].y;
 
            //
            //Получение данных для метода трехточечной прогонки
            //
            double* a  = new double[N+1];
            double* b = new double[N-2];
            double* C = new double[N-2];
            double* F = new double[N-2];
            for (int i = 1; i < N-1; i++) 
                a[i] = X[i+1].x - X[i].x;
            for (int i = 0; i < N - 2; i++)
                F[i] = 6 * ((X[i + 2].y - X[i+1].y) / a[i + 1] - (X[i+1].y - X[i].y) / a[i]);
            for (int i = 0; i < N - 2; i++) {
                C[i] = -2 * (a[i] + a[i + 1]);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < N-2; i++)
                b[i] = a[i + 1];
 
            double* alpha = new double[N+1];
            double* v = new double[N+1];
            double* z = new double[N+1];
            alpha[0] = -0.5; alpha[N] = 0;
            v[0] = 3 * ((X[1].y - X[0].y - A * a[0]) / a[0]) / a[0];
            v[N] = B;
            for (int k = 1; k <= N - 1; k++)
            {
                double temp = C[k] - a[k] * alpha[k - 1];
                alpha[k] = b[k] / temp;
                v[k] = (a[k] * v[k - 1] - F[k]) / temp;
            }
            z[N] = (alpha[N] * v[N - 1] + v[N]) / (1 - alpha[N] * alpha[N - 1]);
            for (int k = N - 1; k > -1; k--)
                z[k] = alpha[k] * z[k + 1] - v[k];
            int number_otr = -1;
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            {
                if (XX < X[i].x) {
                    number_otr = i - 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (number_otr < 0) throw 5.6;
            YY = z[number_otr+1] + ((z[number_otr+1] - z[number_otr]) / a[number_otr+1]) * (XX - X[number_otr].x);
            cout << YY;
        }
        catch (int) {
            IER = 1;
            cout << "IER = " << IER << "\nКубический сплайн не может быть построен ( N < 3)";
        }
        catch(bool){
            IER = 2;
            cout << "IER = " << IER << "\nНарушен порядок возрастания аргумента в входном векторе X";
        }
        catch (double) 
        {
            IER = 3;
            cout << "IER = " << IER << "\nТочка XX не принадлежит отрезку [x(1) ; x(N)]";
        }
        
    }
    else
        cout << "Ошибка";
 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <clocale>

using namespace std;

struct dot {
    double x, y;
};

//проверка упорядоченности агрументов функции
bool check_order(dot* X, int N) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        if (X[i].x > X[i + 1].x)
            return false;
    return true;
}
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    ifstream input("input.txt");
    ofstream output("output.txt");
    if (input && output) {
        int m, IER = 0;   //N - количество точек
        double XX;       //ХХ - точка в которой мы ищем значение второй производной 
        double A, B;     //Граничные условия
        double YY;       //значение второй производной функции в т. ХХ
        try {

            //
            // Ввод информации 
            //

            input >> m >> XX;
            input >> A >> B;
            if (m < 3) throw - 1;
            dot* X = new dot[m];
            for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)       //аргументы функции
                input >> X[i].x;
            if (!check_order(X, m - 1)) throw true;
            for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)         //значение функции в заданных точках
                input >> X[i].y;

            //
            //Получение данных для метода трехточечной прогонки
            //
            double* a = new double[m];
            double* b = new double[m-1];
            double* c = new double[m-1];
            double* F = new double[m-1];
            for (int i = 1; i <= m - 1; i++)
                a[i] = X[i].x - X[i - 1].x;
            for (int i = 1; i <= m - 2; i++)
                F[i] = 6 * ((X[i + 1].y - X[i].y) / a[i + 1] - (X[i].y - X[i - 1].y) / a[i]);
            for (int i = 1; i <= m - 2; i++) {
                c[i] = -2 * (a[i] + a[i + 1]);
            }
            for (int i = 1; i <= m - 2; i++)
                b[i] = a[i + 1];

            double* alpha = new double[m];
            double* beta = new double[m];
            double* z = new double[m];
            alpha[0] = -0.5; alpha[N] = 0;
            beta[0] = 33 * ((X[1].y - X[0].y - A * a[0]) / a[0]) / a[0];
            beta[m - 1] = B;
            for (int k = 1; k <= m - 2; k++)
            {
                double temp = 1 / (c[k] - a[k] * alpha[k - 1]);
                alpha[k] = b[k] * temp;
                beta[k] = (a[k] * beta[k - 1] - F[k]) * temp;
            }
            z[m - 1] = (beta[m - 1] + alpha[m - 1] * beta[m - 2]) / (1 - alpha[m - 1] * alpha[m - 2]);
            for (int k = m - 2; k > -1; k--)
                z[k] = alpha[k] * z[k + 1] + beta[k];
            int number_otr = -1;
            for (int i = 0; i <= m-1; i++)
            {
                if (XX < X[i].x) {
                    number_otr = i - 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (number_otr < 0 || number_otr > m-1) throw 5.6;
            YY = z[number_otr + 1] + ((z[number_otr + 1] - z[number_otr]) / a[number_otr + 1]) * (XX - X[number_otr + 1].x);
            output << "Значение второй производной функции YY = " <<  YY << "\nИндикатор ошибки IER = " << IER;
        }
        catch (int) {
            IER = 1;
            cout << "IER = " << IER << "\nКубический сплайн не может быть построен ( N < 3)";
        }
        catch (bool) {
            IER = 2;
            cout << "IER = " << IER << "\nНарушен порядок возрастания аргумента в входном векторе X";
        }
        catch (double)
        {
            IER = 3;
            cout << "IER = " << IER << "\nТочка XX не принадлежит отрезку [x(1) ; x(N)]";
        }

    }
    else
        cout << "Ошибка";

}
```

Comment: а на вопрос («где я допустил ошибку в коде?») ответа нет.